# Query data in subdirectories in Hive Partitions using Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, parquet

How can I force spark sql to recursively get data stored in parquet format from subdirectories ?  In Hive, I could achieve this by setting few Hive configs.

```
set hive.input.dir.recursive=true;
set hive.mapred.supports.subdirectories=true;
set hive.supports.subdirectories=true;
set mapred.input.dir.recursive=true;
```

I tried to set these configs through spark sql queries but I get 0 records all the times compared to hive which get me the expected results. I also put these confs in hive-site.xml file but nothing changed. How can I handle this issue ?

Spark Version : 2.1.0
I used Hive 2.1.1  on emr-5.3.1

By the way, this issue one appears while using parquet files while with JSON it works fine.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out an answer to this question myself.

Comment: @IceMan I posted the answer now, I hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution for this problem is to force spark to Hive Parquet reader by using hive context which would make spark able to read files recursively.

Comment: I have the same problem with Parquet data and some sub partitions I want to ignore, do you have more details about your solution please?
I use Spark SQL that I run from STS or Livy, creating a Hive table like that:

CREATE TABLE xxx.yyy (...)
STORED AS PARQUET
LOCATION 's3://bucket/path/'
TBLPROPERTIES('mapred.input.dir.recursive'='true', 'hive.supports.subdirectories'='true', 'hive.mapred.supports.subdirectories'='true', 'hive.input.dir.recursive'='true')
PARTITIONED BY (year int, month int , day int);

then I run 'msck repair table xxx.yyy;'
but I dont see the data when I query it

Answer (score 0):

In Spark 2.3, you can just load the top-level directory and Spark will automatically recurse through the lower directories. For example, on HDFS, I have:

```
drwxr-xr-x   - impala hive          0 2019-08-12 12:36 /user/hive/warehouse/prd.db/schedules/departure_year=2009
drwxr-xr-x   - impala hive          0 2019-08-12 12:36 /user/hive/warehouse/prd.db/schedules/departure_year=2010
drwxr-xr-x   - impala hive          0 2019-08-12 12:36 /user/hive/warehouse/prd.db/schedules/departure_year=2011
drwxr-xr-x   - impala hive          0 2019-08-12 12:36 /user/hive/warehouse/prd.db/schedules/departure_year=2012
```

And so on. I can read this using:

```
spark.read.parquet("hdfs://name.node.server:8020/user/hive/warehouse/prd.db/schedules")
```

The resulting DataFrame will have a column `departure_year` that corresponds to the directory name.